# Adding GUI elements on click works only once

Tags: java, user-interface

The problem is very simple. A click on a button will add another button. This also works. But only once, and I want that with every click another button is added below the previous one.

Can you tell me where the problem is?

Here's what I've already tried:
Different layout, because I assumed that the buttons are on top of each other.
A "GUI Refresh", because I thought the interface should be updated after the click... but it didn't work.
In my last attempt I created a new object of the class every time I clicked... unfortunately it didn't work either.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MVCView();
            }
        });

    }
}

public class MVCView extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MVCView() {

        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout();
        setLayout(bl);
        this.setTitle("Test");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setExtendedState(this.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        this.getContentPane().add(addNewRow(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JComponent addNewRow() {

        JPanel getSouthPanel = new JPanel();
        getSouthPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton plus = new JButton("Add new Row");

        plus.addActionListener(new MVCControllerAddLine(this));

        getSouthPanel.add(plus, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        return getSouthPanel;
    }

}

public class MVCControllerAddLine implements ActionListener{

    private MVCView view;
    MVCViewNodeContainer mvcViewNodeContainer = new MVCViewNodeContainer();

    public MVCControllerAddLine(MVCView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        view.getContentPane().add(mvcViewNodeContainer.addNewNodeContainer());
        view.revalidate();
        view.validate();
        view.repaint();

    }

}

public class MVCViewNodeContainer{

    private JPanel panel;

    MVCView view;

    public MVCViewNodeContainer() {
        addNewNodeContainer();
    }


    public JComponent addNewNodeContainer() {

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JButton addNode = new JButton("Add Node");
        addNode.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 120));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);

        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        panel.add(addNode, gbc);

        panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(150, 100));

        return panel;
    }

}
```

Let me know if you need more code. I have tried to leave out unnecessary.

Thank you very much for your help.

Many greetings and a nice weekend

A456B123

Comment: Not a valid [mcve] without runnable code -- we need a main method, code that we can compile and run. Also, you'll want to get rid of the "I am a beginner...", "I searched on Google..." fluff, and instead post only information that helps us to understand the problem itself.

Comment: Also, your code looks to be unnecessarily convoluted? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is you are trying to use a [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) incorrectly.

A border layout lays out a container, arranging and resizing its components to fit in five regions: north, south, east, west, and center. **Each region may contain no more than one component**, and is identified by a corresponding constant: NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST, and CENTER.

Your code here:

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        view.getContentPane().add(mvcViewNodeContainer.addNewNodeContainer());
        view.revalidate();
        view.validate();
        view.repaint();

    }
```

Is adding your "NodeContainers" to the same region of the BorderLayout each time. You would need to have a panel with a different layout that you put in one of the regions and add your buttons or "NodeContainers" to that panel instead.

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution. :)

Have a nice weekend